# How to read a utf-8 encoded file in python using 7zip (lzma)

Tags: python, string, encoding, compression, lzma

I'm compressing a file using:

```
import lzma
myData = ("12+34+113+32+81+92+27...").encode()
obj = lzma.LZMAFile(filename, mode="wb")
obj.write(myData)
obj.close()
```

Then i try to open it

```
obj = lzma.LZMAFile(filename, mode="rb")
data = obj.read()
```

but i get UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 0: invalid start byte

Why no errors encoding but error decoding?
I try to compress the string to save bytes.

Comment: It works fine for me, as long as I remove the `s` in `filenames` here: `obj = lzma.LZMAFile(filesname, mode="rb")` to `obj = lzma.LZMAFile(filename, mode="rb")`

Comment: This was a minimal reproductional code. The original is here. 
And i can't fix after trying for a lot of time. Maybe should i develop a module to write files using C? I can't find a solution. https://github.com/StringManolo/dangerous

Comment: There's no need to develop a module to write files using C. Always refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html). Read it closely. Pay particular attention to the function/method signatures. In regards to passing arguments, it appears you're trying everything/anything and hoping for the best.

Answer (score 0):

Starting at line 50 you create a LZMA-compressed file in binary mode with the position arguments being equivalent to `filename=mode, mode="wb"`:

```py
            if compression and verbose:
                 print("Encoding and compress...")
                 aux = (aux[:-1]).encode("utf-8")
                 obj = lzma.LZMAFile(mode, "wb")
                 print("Writing to file")
                 obj.write(aux)
                 obj.close()
                 return 0
```

You then write `aux`, which is of type `bytes`, to the LZMA-compressed file.

Starting at line 121 you call `lzma.open()` with 3 positional arguments, which the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html#lzma.open) shows is not valid. You can have at most 2 positional arguments, and then everything else must be specified with keyword arguments. In addition to that, `r+b` is not listed as a valid value for the `mode` argument. The documentation states:

> The mode argument can be any of "r", "rb", "w", "wb", "x", "xb", "a" or "ab" for binary mode, or "rt", "wt", "xt", or "at" for text mode. The default is "rb".

```py
            if compression:
                print("Staring decompression...")
                with lzma.open(files[i], "r+b", "utf-8") as lzmaFile:
#                obj = lzma.LZMAFile(files[i], mode="r")
                    fContent = lzmaFile.read()
```

When you originally wrote to the lzma file, you wrote a `bytes` object. When you read the lzma file, you again get the same `bytes` object. To get your original `str`, call the `decode()` method of the `bytes` object, with the same encoding used to encode it (in this case, `utf-8`).

```py
            if compression:
                print("Staring decompression...")
                with lzma.open(files[i]) as f:
                    uncompressed_str = f.read().decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Actually found the bug. I opended the file before and was crashing because of that. Anyways thank's for your time and your good response. When i get more reputation i'll mark your answer as the solution.